# bitmap button not displaying in 3D style

Tags: mfc

The below code should display a bitmap button on my dialog.

```
CImage image;
hr = image.Load(_T("myimage.png")); // just change extension to load jpg
bitmap.Attach(image.Detach());
m_button.ModifyStyle(0,BS_BITMAP);
m_button.SetBitmap(bitmap);
```

The button contains the image. However it is only 2-D rather than the desired 3-D style. I have set the owner drawn property to false, but this has not changed the behavior.

Does anyone see anything wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. In the resource designer preview it was rendered correctly. But at runtime later on, it was rendered as a button with a classical style, which means not 3d but 2d with frames.

Solution for this was for me. In my dialogs `OnInitDialog()` method i just added the following line and it worked like a charm:

```
CMFCVisualManager::SetDefaultManager(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCVisualManagerWindows));
```

Answer (score 0):

- What is the type of m_button
- Are you initializing the visual style manager correctly if you're using CMFCButton
- Have you set the correct style of the button in the resource editor (3d)
- If you're creating the button at runtime, post your Create() call